# Angular async validator's state not reflected in form field's error state

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an an async validator on a `zip` field:

```
zip: ['', {
            validators: [
              Validators.required,
              Validators.minLength(5),
              Validators.maxLength(5)
            ],
            asyncValidators: [
              adPostFormValidators.isValidZip(this.locationService)
            ]
          },
      ],
```

However, the field doesn't seem to reflect the error that comes from the async validator until I click out of the field. For example, this is before I click out (the `null` is the field's error state):

[image]

I know that the async validator has run because I output its results into the console:

[image]

Then, when I click out or lose focus, the error state is now accurate:

[image]

However, the validator was not run again, as nothing new was logged into the console.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution / the cause of this?

Comment: Just added my answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems that because I'm using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, I had to manually mark async validators for check:

```
ref.markForCheck()
return { 'Is not a valid zip': { value: control.value } } as ValidationErrors
```

where `ref` is of type `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had to implement it like here to get it working: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200#issuecomment-410539106

Comment: And this solution looks even simpler, probably more closer to what you did: https://codesandbox.io/s/m430q31xpx (though pusing ChangeDetectorRef into the validatorFn feels kind of less clean)